# How do I change wrapper when iframe url changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with an iframe. My page has a banner/header that displays on the page. After the user clicks submit in the iframe form. I want the banner to go away.

http://todayshousingmarketvalues.com/

This is the page. If you put in an address and click submit you'll see what I need. Make up an address. You don't need to use your own. Nothing happens if you don't subscribe.

Comment: You can't, at least not without adjustments/directly, as that iframe is not within the same origin as the referrer domain, therefore, it's subject to the same origin policy.

Comment: Could I test the 'url' or 'src' and run some code if the 'url != original src'?

Comment: @user2730633 iframe SRC doesn't chane when document changes

Comment: @user2730633 are both iframe and main page from the same domain?

Comment: no they aren't on the same domain. src1 = roseporter.smarthomeprice.com

Comment: and src2 = roseporter.smarthomeprice.com/s/sz/smart_targeting/step2/3ttrqc3j/

Answer (score 0):

You can handle iframe's onload event. If both iframe and parent page are on the same domain - you can check iframe's `contentWindow.location.href` value and if it changes - that means user performed an action - hide the banner.

If domains are *not* the same - this approach won't work since access to that property will be denied. In that case you can set a flag on the parent, marking initial load of iframe. And change the flag on consecutive loads, e.g. call something like in iframe onload:

```
    var initialLoad = true;

    function checkURL() {
       if (initialLoad) {
           initialLoad = false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("banner").style.display="none";
        }
     }
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/MMa9w/ see the banner, then type anything and click the button

Comment: Thanks, but they are not on the same domain.

Comment: That what's this code is doing and demo is showing. Use-case for *not* on the same domain.